# JMeter - Test all APIs in the deployed war file

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter

I want to do load testing of all APIs in the deployed war file of my Spring-boot project. Is it possible to configure JMeter to test all APIs in the war ? Or is there a way to programatically get all API names (RequestMapping) in the war file ?

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question in its current state. It's absolutely unclear what are you trying to achieve, not to mention that we don't know what kind of API is that, which inputs and outputs it requires, whether it has authentication, etc.

Comment: @KirilS. why it is unclear ?  I have clearly written that I want to do load testing of all the APIs in my deployed war file. The war file is of a Spring boot project.

Answer (score 2):

If it is running API already (as you said it is deployed war file) you have to know the endpoints (in case you don't, you have to refer to documentation of API, if you are developer of that API you have to have documentation and of course know the endpoints, for documentation refer to here https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-automatically-document-api-endpoints-via-swagger as a starter)

When you find out the information about your endpoints (endpoints, authentication, expected body in case of post, accepted content type and etc) you can use JMetter UI and create your scenarios and also, you can refer to [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com) and get much more help in real time.

Hope it answered your question and solved your problem